# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'device'

Tags: python, google-home

I want to make a tts script to my google home i saw a youtube video on it and really wanted to make it but when i executed the code i got this error and i dont know how to fix it `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'device'`

here is the code that i used (only the part were i got the error)

```
CastDevice = pychromecast.get_chromecasts()
cast = next(cc for cc in CastDevice if cc.device.friendly_name == 'Rum')
cast.wait()
media = cast.media_controller
media.play_media(r.url, content_type='audio/mp3')
media.block_until_active()
media.play()
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(list(CastDevice))`?

Comment: Your error means that at least one element inside of `CastDevice` is a list. So you can't access the `device` method of a list.

Comment: We need to see what are the contents of `list(CastDevice)`, but you can try `next(cc for cc in CastDevice if not isinstance(cc, list) and cc.device.friendly_name == 'Rum')` to see if it happens what you want.

Comment: It didn't fix it but i got a new error `'CastBrowser' object has no attribute 'device'`